# How to refer to part of DOM-element when creating function?

Tags: javascript

In the script underneath I want to include in my function also a paramater that refers to the id `checkboxform` in  `document.checkboxform.checkbox1.checked`.
Something like `document[parameter].checkbox1.checked`.

How can I do this?

```
<script>
    function showHide(el1,el2) {
      if (!document.getElementById) return;
      var heading1 = document.getElementById(el1);
      var heading2 = document.getElementById(el2);
      var showheading1 = document.checkboxform.checkbox1.checked;
      var showheading2 = document.checkboxform.checkbox2.checked;
      heading1.style.display=(showheading1) ? "block": "none";
      heading2.style.display=(showheading2) ? "block": "none";
    }
```

Comment: `document[parameter].checkbox1.checked`.  Use array notation for variables.

Comment: @stefvr You may delete this question as it is too broad.